# Python ctypes how to reject function call with arguments for function taking no arguments

Tags: python, ctypes

In C++, I have created a C linkage function in a shared library like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
extern "C" int myfunc()
{
  std::cout << "Hello myfunc" << std::endl;
  return 1;
}
```

Note the function does not require any arguments, and I would like to generate an error if someone tried to invoke it with arguments.

I intend to invoke the function from python using ctypes like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
from ctypes import *
libmylib = cdll.LoadLibrary("./libmylib.so")
libmylib.myfunc.argtypes = []
return_code = libmylib.myfunc()
print(f"return_code={return_code:d}")
```

When I run the python script it produces the expected output:

```bash
Hello myfunc
return_code=1
```

To test it, I changed the invocation of the function from python to additionally pass some arguments, i.e. the behaviour I want to reject.
For example:

```py
return_code = libmylib.myfunc(123)
#or
return_code = libmylib.myfunc("123")
```

However it still executes myfunc without any error, and appears to simply ignore that I "wrongly" supplied some arguments.

I tried to change the argtypes line, but nothing seemed to have the desired behaviour:

```py
libmylib.myfunc.argtypes = None
#or
libmylib.myfunc.argtypes = ()
```

Is it possible for ctypes to detect and reject the arguments, or do I simply need to accept that myfunc could be called with extra arguments and I should just ignore them, and not get so fussy about it?

I could write a wrapper shim function in python that would detect extra arguments and generate an error when the detection occurs, but really I was hoping to avoid doing that.

Comment: Why would you worry about this?  This is how things work at the C level as well.  There's no enforcement of argument counts.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your constructive comment. I want to avoid a wrong invocation of my function, that might lead the caller of my function to think they have called it a different way to what I intended, so they know *they* made a mistake, not *me*. If they think that are doing something correct, and it is not working the way they expected, then they will contact me and waste my time to explain to them that they are in fact the one doing something that is unsupported.

Comment: Then write an interface. That is a python function in charge of calling the C one. And expose only that python function. `ctypes` is very low level. And check basically nothing. It just does what you tell it to do. Wrong or not. So, anyway, it is a good idea to not expose those "hacky" function. And anyway, I take that some of your function will have some parameters and more complicated return values. So you may want an intermediary function to handle all the `BYREF` or `c_void_p` stuf so that your user don't deal with that.

Comment: @chrslg I get what you are saying, but note I have no arguments for this particular function, so nothing to pass byref, no pointers etc. argtypes seems to do a great job when I do have simple arguments to pass that it type checks for me.  So I was reasonably expecting it would also check the number of arguments I am passing, but it seems not.  So indeed I will write a shim wrapper in python, but I was still hoping perhaps I missed something and there is a way to get ctypes to do what I thought was an obvious thing someone would want to do.

Comment: You did not miss anything, @joe90. This is [by design](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.argtypes): _functions using the C calling convention accept additional, unspecified arguments as well._

Comment: @EmilioSilva - thanks very much for the reference... `functions using the C calling convention accept additional, unspecified arguments as well`. says it all really. i will now get busy writing my shims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by EmilioSilva in his comment, this is by design.
Quoting from:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.argtypes

> functions using the C calling convention accept additional, unspecified arguments as well

So to get the desired behaviour we need a shim wrapper.

In the case we are considering where the function has no arguments, it is a very simple shim wrapper:

```py
def myfunc():
  return libmylib.myfunc()
```

Calling myfunc with no args works as desired:

```py
return_code = myfunc()
print(f"return_code={return_code:d}")
```

Also calling myfunc with args fails as desired:

```
# trigger an error when the caller tries to do this
return_code = myfunc(123)
```

This is the error...

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmyfunc.py", line 15, in <module>
    return_code = myfunc(123)
TypeError: myfunc() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```